# Is creating a SuperTrait the only way to do this?

Tags: rust

I created one-file-only project here: https://github.com/frederikhors/rust-clean-architecture-with-db-transactions-one-file.

I'm trying to change at runtime which repository to use based on a variable.

Here is the reproduction: https://www.rustexplorer.com/b/8qv1c2 (if the browser answers with a 500 error page, just reload).

And this is the error:

```
error[E0658]: cannot cast `dyn RepoSuperTrait` to `dyn CommandsRepoTrait`, trait upcasting coercion is experimental
   --> src\main.rs:376:24
    |
376 |         commands_repo: db_repo.clone(),
    |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    |
    = note: see issue #65991 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/65991> for more information
    = note: required when coercing `Arc<dyn RepoSuperTrait>` into `Arc<(dyn CommandsRepoTrait + 'static)>`
```

I would like to use one of the following suggestions I get on a forum:

> 2. Extract all the functionality you need into an object-safe trait and use a Box

> 3. Extract all the functionality you need into an object-safe trait and use the on-stack dynamic dispatch pattern (https://rust-unofficial.github.io/patterns/idioms/on-stack-dyn-dispatch.html) (essentially the same as above, with fewer heap allocations but slightly more code)

What am I doing wrong?

How can I fix this?

The relevant code is:

```rust
trait RepoSuperTrait: services::commands::CommandsRepoTrait + services::queries::QueriesRepoTrait {}

impl<T: services::commands::CommandsRepoTrait + services::queries::QueriesRepoTrait> RepoSuperTrait for T {}

pub struct Deps {
    pub commands_repo: Arc<dyn services::commands::CommandsRepoTrait>,
    pub queries_repo: Arc<dyn services::queries::QueriesRepoTrait>,
}

let use_postgres = false;

let db_repo: Arc<dyn RepoSuperTrait + 'static> = if use_postgres {
    let pg_pool = Arc::new(sqlx::PgPool::connect("postgres://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/postgres").await.unwrap());

    Arc::new(repositories::postgres::Repo::new(pg_pool))
} else {
    Arc::new(repositories::inmemory::Repo::new())
};

let deps = Arc::new(Deps {
    commands_repo: db_repo.clone(),
    queries_repo: db_repo,
});
```

Comment: `RepoSuperTrait` is a misnomer here, it's a *sub* trait of both `CommandsRepoTrait` and `QueriesRepoTrait`, they are the *super* traits.

Comment: I'm not understanding what a supertrait is anymore now... Isn't this a way to create a super trait for both `CommandsRepoTrait` and `QueriesRepoTrait` that I need to contruct `Deps`?

Comment: In the expression `trait Sub: Super` `Sub` is the sub trait, `Super` is the super trait.

Comment: Ok. How can I fix the issue then using the supertrait?

Comment: Read the [Tracking issue for dyn upcasting coercion](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/65991) it's not possible yet without nightly & `#![feature(trait_upcasting)]`